# spring-integration MockIntegrationContext ReactiveStreamConsumer: IllegalArgumentException: 'subscriber' must not be null in the "...endpoint"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

My test is failing because of the missing 'subscriber' field `IllegalArgumentException: 'subscriber' must not be null in the "...endpoint"`

```java
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        ArgumentCaptor<Message<?>> captor = messageArgumentCaptor();
        CountDownLatch receiveLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mockMessageHandler(captor).handleNext(m -> receiveLatch.countDown());
        this.mockIntegrationContext
                .substituteMessageHandlerFor(
                        "test2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1",
                        mockMessageHandler);
        this.integrationFlowWithReactiveConsumerHandler.getInputChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>("test2"));
        assertThat(receiveLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        verify(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(any());
        assertThat(captor.getValue().getPayload())
                .isEqualTo("reactive-message-text");
    }
```

It's failing here in `MockIntegrationContext.java`, calling `substituteMessageHandlerFor` method, when endpoint is `ReactiveStreamsConsumer`

```java
    public void substituteMessageHandlerFor(String consumerEndpointId, // NOSONAR - complexity
            MessageHandler mockMessageHandler, boolean autoStartup) {

        Object endpoint = this.beanFactory.getBean(consumerEndpointId, IntegrationConsumer.class);
        if (autoStartup && endpoint instanceof Lifecycle) {
            ((Lifecycle) endpoint).stop();
        }
        DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor(endpoint);
        Object targetMessageHandler = directFieldAccessor.getPropertyValue(HANDLER);
        Assert.notNull(targetMessageHandler, () -> "'handler' must not be null in the: " + endpoint);
        if (endpoint instanceof ReactiveStreamsConsumer) {
            Object targetSubscriber = directFieldAccessor.getPropertyValue("subscriber");
            Assert.notNull(targetSubscriber, () -> "'subscriber' must not be null in the: " + endpoint);
```

The handler endpoint bean is `...:reactive-outbound-channel-adapter` which is being instantiated using ReactiveStreamConsumer constructor, where the 'subsciber' field is null by default.

```java
    /**
     * Instantiate an endpoint based on the provided {@link MessageChannel} and {@link ReactiveMessageHandler}.
     * @param inputChannel the channel to consume in reactive manner.
     * @param reactiveMessageHandler the {@link ReactiveMessageHandler} to process messages.
     * @since 5.3
     */
    public ReactiveStreamsConsumer(MessageChannel inputChannel, ReactiveMessageHandler reactiveMessageHandler) {
        Assert.notNull(inputChannel, "'inputChannel' must not be null");
        this.inputChannel = inputChannel;
        this.handler = new ReactiveMessageHandlerAdapter(reactiveMessageHandler);
        this.reactiveMessageHandler = reactiveMessageHandler;
        this.publisher = IntegrationReactiveUtils.messageChannelToFlux(inputChannel);
        this.subscriber = null;
        this.lifecycleDelegate =
                reactiveMessageHandler instanceof Lifecycle ? (Lifecycle) reactiveMessageHandler : null;
    }
```

During the test it creates the endpoint bean, and then during the `substituteMessageHandlerFor` it throws an exception of missing `subscriber` field

Integration flow is simple with single DB reactive handler.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the testing framework. When we introduced a `ReactiveMessageHandler` support into that `ReactiveStreamsConsumer`, we just missed to adjust `MockIntegrationContext` logic respectively.

There is no way to mock a reactive endpoint at the moment as any reasonable workaround. However you can introduce some intermediate endpoint into the flow, e.g. `bridge()` and mock just this one without any return. So, your test will pass and nothing will be send to the real reactive endpoint in the end.

Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will look into that ASAP.

Comment: A GH issue we are talking about: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3986